# Why log4j doesn't display formatted XML content

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I need to print an XML content causing exception in our application error log file, so i format it. and pass it to log4j error method as follow:

```
String jeton = LoggerUtility.format(ssoLoginInputXml.toString());
log.error(jeton);
```

The problem is XML is displayed in only one line, here's what i get.

```
2018/08/16 12:09:45.699|12|127.0.0.1|http-bio-8080-exec-8|A1D1E9E080E70CDBE7207B6D45BB6CC8|ERROR|SQAC|<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <sar:_in xmlns:sar="http://sar"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sar_in.xsd">   <data>     <budget id="200"/>     <channel id="WEB"/>     <appcode id="CATIS"/>     <mdp id="NON"/>     <sign id="LOGINPASSWORD">       <login id=""/>       <password id=""/>     </sign>   </data> </sar:_in>
```

Here's the content of of he jeton object as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sar:_in
xmlns:sar="http://sar"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sar_in.xsd">
 <data>
    <budget id="200"/>
    <channel id="WEB"/>
    <appcode id="CATIS"/>
    <mdp id="NON"/>
    <sign id="LOGINPASSWORD">
        <login id=""/>
        <password id=""/>
    </sign>
</data>
</sar:_in>
```

Any one has an idea, is it a configuration to add to log4j?

Comment: What does `LoggerUtility.format` do ?

Comment: Formats the XML file.

Comment: Does `System.out.println(jeton)` give the expected output ?

Comment: @Amira Post it please.

Comment: @Arnaud yes it works with th SOP.